# Why is updating dependencies in composer so slow?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm using composer (http://getcomposer.org/) to manage dependencies in Symfony2 (Symfony v 2.8) here https://poweredtemplate.com

I have a problem with the fact that when I add a new dependency in composer.json, for example "composer require hwi / oauth-bundle", the dependency is added for a very long time (~20min), or gives me the error "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ..."

Is there any way to make this process faster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do a few things:

1) use `--prefer-dist`

2) check if Xdebug is loaded.

`php -m | grep xdebug`

3) you can additonaly enable verbosity to see what operations are taking too long

```
--prefer-dist -vvv
```

Comment: The xdebug directive was included. After disabling xdebux , the composer began to work faster. Thanks.

Comment: In my environment (xdebug off and add --prefer-dist), I felt about twice as fast. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the owner from the `~/.composer` folder.

`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer`

Without this permission, composer can't install the packages in the cache folder.